# Actionbarsherlock+android-support-v4-r6-googlemaps+sliding menu

Tags: android, menu, actionbarsherlock, dalvik, sliding

I'm trying to combine Jeremy Feinstein's sliding menu lib with actionbarshelock.
Problem is - in order to present a map within a fragment i used android-support-v4-r6-googlemaps which causing me a lot of problems.
the sliding lib has a dependency to a actionbarshelock lib where android-support-v4.jar is replaced with android-support-v4-r6-googlemaps in order to show the map within a fragment (as explained here: http://blog.xavirigau.com/?p=39).

Adding the sliding lib to my project throws this error: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1, which i found related to similar jar files.
I guess it has to do something with the jar i modified and the v13 one as shown in the following pic:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MNP3.png
I can't seem to find how to delete the redundant jar.
Help anyone?

thanks in regard,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock comes with the jar for the support package and this other library properly does as well. You could try to combine the libraries in order for them to work together. You have the source for both so it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Ok, so I combined the two and still when using this lib in my project I get the dalvik error, I still have the two jars which i suspect causing this in the lib's dependency folder (the jars are android-support-v4-r6-googlemaps and android-support-v13) - I can't seem to find how to delete one of them...
http://i.imgur.com/GPMTJ.jpg

Comment: Actionbar uses v4 so track down v13 in the other project. If you can't remove it from the other project you probarbly have to consider alternatives.

Comment: It should be in the libs folder. If not in the libs folder you'll have to remove in from the eclipse menu (the one you had a screenshot from).

Comment: since I couldn't remove the jar as you suggested I ended up solving this by combining the two libs into one lib. Thanks for focusing me in solving this problem.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Hope you don't run into any issues along the way.

Comment: @Warpzit I am having the same problem, but I have solved this error. But now my issue is that the Mapview is lost when selecting other fragments :(
How did you solve the issue ?